# How to echo video element of videojs

Tags: php, jquery, video.js

There will be a quote mismatch after data-setup attribute. Is there any way  to achieve this by echoing. I dont want to close php tag and then write html.

```
echo '<video-js data-setup='{"controls": true, "autoplay": false,"preload":"auto"}'>
<source src="DASH_360.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="DASH_360.mp4" type="video/webm">
</video-js>'
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping the quotes?

Comment: _"I dont want to close php tag and then write html"_ - Why not? It would be my suggestion since it would make your code easier to read (IDE's will be able to syntax highlight the HTML) and less error prone since you won't need to escape the quotes.

Comment: Oops. escaping worked. Thank you.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson this is inside cluster of conditional statements so i thought its a better option to find a way in echoing.

Comment: The better option in this case is what makes the code most readable and maintainable. If that means closing and opening the PHP block, then that would be my recommendation.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I will try it then. Thank you.

Comment: @Mentalist If your question was answered in the comments, please mark it as closed so that others know it is already answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape character(/) -
You can use an escape character / to escape quotes to make it part of the string in PHP.

Below is an example.

```
 echo '<video-js data-setup=\'{"controls": true, "autoplay": false,"preload":"auto"}\'> <source src="DASH_360.mp4" type="video/mp4"> <source src="DASH_360.mp4" type="video/webm"> </video-js>';
```

but you can also try closing and opening PHP tag that is also a neater approach, it helps in making code more readable and gives you better control over it.

```
?> <video-js data-setup='{"controls": true, "autoplay": false,"preload":"auto"}'> <source src="DASH_360.mp4" type="video/mp4"> <source src="DASH_360.mp4" type="video/webm"> </video-js>'; <?php
```